# react-stockchart: cannot convert JSX to TSX

Tags: svg, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I have an example of the [react-stockchart](https://github.com/rrag/react-stockcharts) chart in JSX:
JSX plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:b993d5fcc5c09dd66a6e?p=preview

I want to add JSX to an existing TypeScript project, so I changed the file extension from JSX to TSX and did other convertions from this site:
http://slidedeck.io/thewazir/Using-Typescript-with-JSX

But the problem still remains, this code doesn't compile:

```
CandleStickChartWithBollingerBandOverlay = fitWidth(CandleStickChartWithBollingerBandOverlay);
ReactDOM.render(<CandleStickChartWithBollingerBandOverlay data={data} type="hybrid"/>, document.getElementById("chart"));
```

**fitWidth** source: https://github.com/rrag/react-stockcharts/blob/master/src/lib/helper/fitWidth.jsx
If I remove **fitWidth** it is drawn with incorrect width:

```
ReactDOM.render(<CandleStickChartWithBollingerBandOverlay data={data} type="hybrid" width={800}/>, document.getElementById("chart"));
```

I tried this code, it doesn't work (nothing is drawn at all):

```
var StockChartComponent = fitWidth(CandleStickChartWithBollingerBandOverlay);
ReactDOM.render(<StockChartComponent data={data} type="hybrid"/>, document.getElementById("chart"));
```

And this doesn't work too:

```
var StockChartComponent = fitWidth(new CandleStickChartWithBollingerBandOverlay());
ReactDOM.render(<StockChartComponent data={data} type="hybrid"/>, document.getElementById("chart"));
```

Comment: Could you add a plunker or share any error messages? I am not familiar with TS, but it is on my mind to add support for it in a future version

Comment: No error messages, it just doesn't pass compilation and when it passes compilation it doesn't show anything at all. TypeScript doesn't allow working with classes as JavaScript does. Function fitWidth supposes to receive type or object instance?

Comment: it accepts type. since you say `fitWidth` is the culprit, you could rewrite it to fit your need?

`fitWidth` finds the width available and returns a new higher order component which has a pre defined width of the component you pass as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the main tsx file:

```
export function initialize(data, element) {
    var StockChartComponent = fitWidth(CandleStickChartWithBollingerBandOverlay);    
    ReactDOM.render(<StockChartComponent data={data} type="hybrid" height={800} />, element);       
}
```

This is the fixed fitWidth.tsx:

```
import React = require('react');
import ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

export function fitWidth(WrappedComponent, withRef = true) {
class ResponsiveComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
    static getDisplayName(Series) {
        var name = Series.displayName || Series.name || "Series";
        return name;
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        displayName: `fitWidth(${ResponsiveComponent.getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleWindowResize = this.handleWindowResize.bind(this);
        this.getWrappedInstance = this.getWrappedInstance.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleWindowResize);
        var el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        var w = (el.parentNode as Element).clientWidth;

        /* eslint-disable react/no-did-mount-set-state */
        this.setState({
            width: w
        });
        /* eslint-enable react/no-did-mount-set-state */
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleWindowResize);
    }
    handleWindowResize() {
        var el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        var w = (el.parentNode as Element).clientWidth;
        this.setState({
            width: w
        });
    }
    getWrappedInstance() {
        return (this.refs as any).component;
    }
    render() {
        var ref = withRef ? { ref: "component" } : {};

        if (this.state && this.state.width) {
            return <WrappedComponent width={this.state.width} {...this.props} {...ref} />;
        } else {
            return <div />;
        }
    }
}

return ResponsiveComponent;
```

}